# Does a Dart WebComponent have access to its DOM element

Tags: dart, dart-webui

Inside my class that extends WebComponent, is there a standard way to access the DOM element that represents the root of this instance?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use getShadowRoot():

```dart
getShadowRoot('x-some-component').style.color = '#F00';
```

Comment: and 'x-some-component' is the id of the HTML element? how is that different than query('x-some-component')?  doesn't that mean I have to store that ID somewhere?

Comment: No, x-some-component is the element name (x-click-counter in the [WebUI example](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/web-ui/#components)). Query will traverse the DOM and find nodes with the matching ID/class, while getShadowRoot() automatically returns the corresponding node. Consider a component that on a click changes it's color to red. Now add two of these components to the page. Using query, the first component will always change color, whether you click on the first or second component. Using getShadowRoot(), the component that changes color will be the one that you clicked on.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways. First is to use `_root`. The second option is to use `getShadowRoot()` as mentioned by Pixel Elephant.

Some old code relies on `_root`, but don't use it, because it's being deprecated and is going away. `getShadowRoot()` will be better for auto completion in IDE as well.

This is what you should do:

```dart
getShadowRoot('x-your-element').classes.add('your-element');
```

Comment: Please see comment on Pixel Elephant's answer.

Comment: @brooks94 you don't need to store anything. `x-your-element` is simply the name of the web component e.g.: `<element name="x-your-element" ...>`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's a good way to do this,
But I use something like this:

```
inserted() {
  var root = shadowRoot != null? shadowRoot: this;
  var element = root.query("something in the webcomponent dom");
  element.text = "Hello from webcomponent";
}
```

This code is compliant with both shadow dom and standar way.